# How to enable Miracast on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, mirroring, miracast

I'm using `Windows 10 Pro N` and I want to mirror my phone screen to my Computer but I am unable to do so as it says "This device doesn't support Miracast" on `Projecting to this PC`.
[image: Projecting to this PC]

I went to do `dxdiag` to see if it supports or not and there it is listed as  `Miracast: Available, no HDCP` but when I go to Nvidia Control Panel it says HDCP is supported for my device.
[image: Nvidia Control Panel]

I'm running 5900x with GTX 670, and I remember casting my screen before I installed Windows 10 N.
I have posted picture for more clarification.  all the supports on Microsoft pages don't seem to work for me.

[image]

Comment: Your system does not actually support Miracast.  The output of `dxdiag` is miss leading.  You must have a display driver that supports it and a wireless driver that supports it.  Your display driver does not support it.

Comment: @Ramhound so upgrading my graphics card and it's driver would fix the issue I'm having?

Comment: No; modern Nvidia drivers nor modern AMD drivers support Miracast

Comment: How am I supposed to cast my phone screen to the computer then?

Comment: I am simply explaining the reason you are having problems using Miracast.  If you have an Android phone there is a SE exchange for that likewise, there is an Apple SE also.

Answer (score 0):

My Windows 11 system also reports "Miracast: Available, no HDCP" through the dxdiag tool. However, I was able find a solution for screen sharing after hours of struggle and all views saying it's impossible to do so.

This software does the work for me: [AirMyPC](https://www.airmypc.com/). Unfortunately, they solve this problem, and Microsoft devs still don't.

It might also be worth mentioning that if you need to cast a video or audio to the TV, you should try this [tutorial](https://www.businessinsider.com/guides/tech/how-to-cast-windows-desktop-to-tv) teaching "Another method to cast to a smart TV".

Good Luck everyone!